# How to switch off registration window on ASUS laptop?

Tags: windows-8.1, asus-laptop

I'd like to switch off the registration window of a Windows 8.1 ASUS laptop at start up using the task manager.

The task manager does not seem to have a disable function for any particular task, so how do I turn this annoying window off at the start up?

Comment: Have you considered registering?

Comment: @Xavierjazz made me laugh but not really helpful ;) - George, consider looking at other questions on how to disable items at start up.

Comment: Thanks, I did look and even though as a beginner I found the task manager and opened it , even after following advice from other sources I could not find a way to shut it off ! I spent a couple of hours and gave in frustration. But I guess it's like anything when you know how it's easy. ha ha. I'll keep looking thanks.

Comment: Yea, there are already good answers for finding EVERYTHING that loads with Windows. You're not trying to stop the process while it is already running, you're trying to stop the process from starting each time your computer starts.